# With cordova-plugin-facebook4@4.2.1 "User cancelled." error thrown immediately after invoking the login method

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, ionic3

Facebook login was working fine for both Android and iOS like 2 weeks ago, but for some reason lately on iOS it has been crashing, whenever someone from iOS tries to login it sends out the error of:
"User cancelled"

I tried to fix it by updating the plugin, however the error persists.
I do not think there's something wrong with my code since Android still works and iOS used to work, and I've not changed anything from the login code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

- Remove plugin
- Remove BOTH Android and iOS platforms (cordova platform remove android // cordova platform remove ios)
- Reinstall plugin
- Verify that it's up to date npm outdated (I think that's the command)

Problem went away, the deal was to FORCE the update on the plugin, which won't happen if any of the platforms is still installed by the time you try to re-install it again.